# Write class with constructor that takes no argument

Tags: python

Property is a list that stores Food items.

This is the Class Food that I have done previously

```
class Food(object):
    def __init__(self,name,nutrition,good_until):
        self.name = name
        self.nutrition = nutrition
        self.good_until = good_until
        self.age = 0
```

Methods:

– Constructor takes in no argument.

– get_stock_names(): returns a list of strings that represents the names of
all food items in the stock.

– load(food): add the food object to stock.

```
class VendingMachine(object):
    def load(self,food):
        self.food = food
        return self.food
    def get_stock_names(self):
        self.obj = []
        self.obj.append(self.load())


machine = VendingMachine()
apple = Food("apple", 70, 7)
banana = Food("banana", 100, 4)
yoghurt = FermentedFood("yoghurt", 50, 0, 10)
machine.load(banana)
machine.load(apple)
machine.load(yoghurt)
machine.load(apple)
print(machine.get_stock_names())
```

I should get `["banana", "apple", "yoghurt", "apple"]`

Which part is wrong???

Answer (score 1):

You should still have an `__init__` method that initializes the variables as follows:

```
class VendingMachine(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foods = []

    def load(self,food):
        self.foods.append(food)
        return self.foods

    def get_stock_names(self):
        return [i.name for i in self.foods]

machine = VendingMachine()
apple = Food("apple", 70, 7)
banana = Food("banana", 100, 4)
yoghurt = FermentedFood("yoghurt", 50, 0, 10)
machine.load(banana)
machine.load(apple)
machine.load(yoghurt)
machine.load(apple)
print(machine.get_stock_names())
["banana", "apple", "yoghurt", "apple"]
```

Comment: When machine.get_stock_names() is an empty list, I should get None for machine.load(food)  @sshashank124